# Make a custom keyboard in Android having the same behavior as the soft keyboard

Tags: android, android-widget

So, today I decided to try out Android, so please understand that I am a beginner in it.

What I want to achieve right now is to have a EditText, and a set of buttons to be used to enter data into the EditText.

What I've done currently is stick a set of button widgets in the XML layout, and I use this code to make the buttons insert stuff into the EditText:

```
    final EditText inputline = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textentry); 

    final Button my_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.my_btn);
    my_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            inputline.append("a");
        }
    });
```

This kind of works, but I need help with a few issues:

- it always appends the character at the end of the string, not at the current cursor position
- similarly, when I call `inputline.selectAll()` and press my button, it inserts the text at the end of the string again; whereas I want it to delete the text first (as it's selected) and then insert the character
- it seems tedious to write all that code for each of the buttons I have. Is there a better way to do this altogether?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now pretty much solved by replacing `inputline.append("a");` etc. with my custom function, `lineInsert()`, which you can see below.

```
public void lineInsert(CharSequence text) {
    final EditText inputline = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textentry);
    int start = inputline.getSelectionStart();
    int end = inputline.getSelectionEnd();
    inputline.getText().replace(Math.min(start,end), Math.max(start,end), text, 0, text.length());
    inputline.setSelection(inputline.getSelectionEnd());
}
```

This has the same behavior as the soft keyboard.